# Rolling mean with customized window with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to customize the window of the rolling_mean function?

```
data
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Let's say the window is set to 2, that is to calculate the average of 2 datapoints before and after the obervation including the observation. Say the 3rd observation. In this case, we will have `(1+2+3+4+5)/5 = 3`. So on and so forth.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Compute the usual rolling mean with a forward (or backward) window and then use the `shift` method to re-center it as you wish.

```
data_mean = pd.rolling_mean(data, window=5).shift(-2)
```

If you want to average over 2 datapoints before and after the observation (for a total of 5 datapoints) then make the `window=5`.

For example,

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.Series(range(1, 9))

data_mean = pd.rolling_mean(data, window=5).shift(-2)
print(data_mean)
```

yields

```
0   NaN
1   NaN
2     3
3     4
4     5
5     6
6   NaN
7   NaN
dtype: float64
```

---

As [kadee points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20249149/rolling-mean-with-customized-window-with-pandas/20249295?noredirect=1#comment56896948_20249295), if you wish to center the rolling mean, then use

```
pd.rolling_mean(data, window=5, center=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I may not illustrate my example well. Let me update my example.

Comment: To re-center, one can also do: data_mean = pd.rolling_mean(data, window=5, center=True)

Comment: @kadee: Thanks for the improvement.

Answer (score 3):

For more current version of Pandas (please see 0.23.4 documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html), you don't have rolling_mean anymore.  Instead, you will use

```
DataFrame.rolling(window, min_periods=None, center=False, win_type=None, on=None, axis=0, closed=None)
```

For your example, it will be:

```
df.rolling(5,center=True).mean()
```